# Turning off Facebook API errors

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to disable the Facebook PHP API from printing certain errors (disable them per api call maybe?) as they occur such as

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request. thrown in [URL] on line [LINE]
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure you want to hide fatal errors? Are you absolutely sure that that is what you want to do? Like, are you really absolutely sure you do not want to be notified about errors of fatal severity???

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I would not like to disable them all, only certain ones. Sorry that I didn't write that in the question. Updating now. This error for example is useless to see according to me. It occurs when I'm trying to delete an action that doesn't exist.